# Python Bleak write_gatt_char fails after Bleak update

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

My Python/Bleak/BleakClient code calls write_gatt_char with my custom UUID and a string of bytes.
This works fine with Bleak version 0.19.0 but fails with version 0.21.1 with the error message: "Could not write value b'my_bytes' to characteristic 0014: Protocol Error 0x0E: Unlikely Error"
I've googled all over trying to find a mention of this Protocol Error and what it means - but no luck.
I'm running on Windows 11 Pro Version 10.0.22621 Build 22621 with Python 3.9.16

I did the Bleak update because the older version has some instabilities with Windows that are supposed to be corrected in the later version.

Anyone have any ideas about how to debug this? Maybe the Bleak client was validated on a different version of Python? Maybe I need to update the Windows BLE driver?

Comment: I just updated my laptop Bluetooth driver to the latest Intel release and that did not fix the problem.

Comment: Aha! I changed the "response" flag from None to True and then to False. The False version works and the other two do not. Of course, setting the flag to False means the write will return immediately, which may cause trouble with subsequent code that relies on the transaction to be complete. But at least I'm making progress.

Comment: Did you end up finding anything else out for this? I'm getting "Unlikely Error" from the Bleak/Bless example code constantly.